# python change string between certain two words

Tags: python, replace

I wrote a script as shown below, I want to replace the strings between  `StartNum` and `/StartNum`  by another variable `n`. How do I define the position between these two strings in Python?

```
f1 = open('name.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('result.txt', 'w')
n=5000
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('(StartNum)(.*)(/StartNum)',str(n)))
    if "StartNum" in line:
        n=n+1
```

Comment: You are probably better off using `lxml` or another XML parsing library to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
re.sub('(StartNum)(.*)(/StartNum)', r"\1boop\3", 'StartNumbworp/StartNum')
```

This replaces `bworp` with `boop`, so the final string it returns is `StartNumboop/StartNum`.

Comment: firstly thx~ but i dont very understand ur code. could u tell me how to change my code above accoring to urs?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub and http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html. You'd want to replace the last argument with the string you intend to substitute, and the second with the substitution.